# How to set '-O3' optimization flag in Android Studio 2.2 or over?(Android NDK)

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, ndk-build

Now I am using Android Studio version 2.2. In previous versions, I created Android.mk and Application.mk and compiled c ++. At that time, I optimized the compilation of c ++ using the -O3 flag. However, since version 2.2, the CmakeLists.txt file is used, and the -O2 flag seems to be input automatically. Is there a way to put -O3 options in CMakeList.txt? Here is the CmakeList text file I created:

```
set(pathOpenCv C:/OpenCV-android-sdk-3.0)
set(pathProject C:/Users/kdhsu/OCR)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")


include_directories(${pathOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathProject}/app/src/main/JniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

file(GLOB Library_SOURCES src/main/cpp/*.cpp)
file(GLOB Library_HEADERS src/main/cpp/*.hpp)

add_library(imported-lib SHARED  ${Library_SOURCES} ${Library_HEADERS} )
set_target_properties(imported-lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( imported-lib  
                       lib_opencv)   

target_link_libraries( native-lib 
                       ${log-lib}
                       imported-lib
                       lib_opencv)
```

I will wait for the right answer. Thanks:)

Comment: Can't you append `-O3` to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, similarly to how you add `-std=gnu++11` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`? You could probably add the flag from your gradle script as well.

Comment: Ah,, thanks! so, i modified this file like this:
`set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)`
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")`
`set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3")`
is it right?